# File upload with Flask app in Apache - Http 400 is returned

Tags: python, apache, flask

I am using `cgi` to deploy the `Flask` app in `Apache 2.4`. The app is deployed and works fine, I can render the pages and download reports and other stuff.

But I can't upload any file. In my local, it works fine, I can upload files. But not in Apache. (Apache 2.4 is installed in Windows Server 2012 R2).

It returns Http response - `400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

I debugged and found the `request.files` is giving an error. Maybe `files` is not present in the `request` object.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'response' : 1, 'msg' : 'No File part'})

    myfile = request.files['file']

    if myfile.filename == '':
        return jsonify({'response' : 1, 'msg' : 'No File selected'})

    myAllowedFile = myfile.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENTIONS
```

My html code for the form is as below-

```
<form id='upload_file' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table id='uploadTable'>
        <tr>
            <td><label for='file'>Select a file:</label><input type='file' name='file' id='uploadfile'></td>

            <td><button id='upload-file-button' type='button' name='file'>Upload</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what error is thrown by `request.files` ? Please add some traceback

Comment: @PRMoureu I added `try-except` to catch the exception. I get this error in the exception - `400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`